# How to refactor these MySQL queries with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, refactoring

I am what many people would consider an amateur programmer, but am trying to embark on the transition to a more professional coder. In doing so, I have been asked by the company I am interning for to refactor some MySQL queries so that I don't have to copy, paste, and edit every single time a new distinct field is added to the database, allowing for the web site to dynamically update itself when unique data is introduced to the DB. I have built a dashboard of sorts that displays information about a particular project. Within each project view there are location-specific JQuery accordions. So far, I have had to copy, paste, and edit new queries for each of these locations, despite the fact that site (location) is a column within the database. I would like to refactor these queries so that I only have to write two queries: one that stores all of the distinct locations into an array, and a second (most likely within a PHP loop - I was thinking foreach) that selects the data I need for each location, storing the data into variables that can then be used to produce individual accordions for all of the rows of a particular location.

Here is what the MySQL query I have right now looks like:

```
    SELECT project, participant, reel, machine, qc_gsr, qc_hr, qc_acz, qc_bre FROM rtcdb.session WHERE site = 'CHI001'
```

This selects the data columns I need when the location (site) is Chicago (CHI001). If I want to find the distinct sites in my table, I can write something like this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT site FROM rtcdb.session;
```

I want to put the query results for each location in separate accordions, and I am also unsure how I will end up doing this. The HTML format of these accordions is as follows:

```
    <h3><i><b>Chicago</b></i></h3>
        <div>
            <div id = "accordion">
                <h4 id="green"><b>Data</b></h4>

                <div>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Project ID</th>
                                <th>Participant ID</th>
                                <th>SEM</th>
                                <th>Kiosk #</th>
                                <th>GSR</th>
                                <th>Heart Rate</th>
                                <th>ACZ</th>
                                <th>ABB</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($chi_results)) {
                                    echo '
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>'.$row["project"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row["participant"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row["reel"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row["machine"].'</td>
                                            <td><img class = "circle" src="'.$row["qc_gsr"].'_circle.png"></td>
                                            <td><img class = "circle" src="'.$row["qc_hr"].'_circle.png"></td>
                                            <td><img class = "circle" src="'.$row["qc_acz"].'_circle.png"></td>
                                            <td><img class = "circle" src="'.$row["qc_bre"].'_circle.png"></td>
                                        </tr> ';
                                    }
                                ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Please if you have any input it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much for viewing this question and I hope to hear some answers!

- JAKE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be sure that any new code you write uses the `mysqli_*` functions and not the old `mysql_*` functions.

If you want to get this data for all the sites at once on a single page, do one query and group it together in php like below. If you want separate pages follow AMADANON's advice.

#### Query Stuff

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(...);
mysqli_select_db(...);
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT site,my,other,column,names,");
$site_info = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $s = $row['site'];
    if(!is_array($site_info[$s])) $site_info[$s] = array();
    $site_info[$s][] = $row;
}
```

#### Page Stuff

```
<?php
foreach($site_info as $site) {
?>
    <div id="accordion">
        <?php echo $site['my'] . $site['column'] . $site['names']; ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one page which shows all sites, you can do the following: add "?site=CHI001" to the end of your link.

In your script, this will show up as `$_GET['site']` (you can use any name you like).

Convert the variable with mysql_real_escape_string - `$site = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['site']);'

DO NOT! attempt to put the variable in directly - this WILL let an attacker run any database command they like! See [php.net article on SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) or take my word for it - it is BAD!

Now you can add this value into your sql - replace `WHERE site = 'CHI001'` with `WHERE site = '$site'`

Now you can test the page, for different sites.